# Formatting currency in Jasper Reports using pattern

Tags: java, jasper-reports, design-patterns, currency-formatting

I have a query which returns amount from a table:

```
select bus_price from mySchema.BusTable;
```

This will return amounts like:

```
526547
123456
456789.25
12478.35
```

I am using above amounts in jasper report.

However, I want the output in the report to be displayed as:

```
$526,547.00
$123,456.00
$456,789.25
$12,478.35
```

JRXML code snippet is:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">        
     <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="700" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>                               
     <textElement/>             
       <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal">
         <![CDATA[$F{BusPrices}]]>
      </textFieldExpression>         
</textField>
```

I know I have to use patterns. However, I am not able to make it work.

Using

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern='$###,##0.00'>
```

is not working.

What am I missing ??

Thanks for reading!

Comment: currently there is no builtin function for that. do you bind it to the datagrid? what language are you using?

Comment: @johntotetwoo: I did not understand your question. I am using DB2 database and sql query language.

Comment: @johntotetwoo, your question is unclear to me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close

```
<textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
```

should work.

You need the "¤" character to make it a "currency" format.

If you download iReports with a version number that matches your server you find out what your options are.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to display currency symbol in $ and currency code is USD use the following pattern in jasper report.
pattern = $ #,##0.00

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on your version of Jasper.

On 3.7.6 I found that specifying the textFieldExpression class as java.util.BigDecimal meant that the pattern isn't applied.  Maybe that version of Jasper doesn't realise it is a number.

If you choose instead specify the textFieldExpression class as being "java.lang.Number", it will use the pattern when you pass a BigDecimal in.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure you have the currency format with thousands separated by comas, ensure you add the pattern below on your textfield

> #,##0.00

and ensure the check box for

> Use 1000 separator is checked.

The above pattern ensures your amount is in currency format with a two decimal place value and a default of 0.00 where the amount is zero.