# How to invert the comma and dot when number formatting

Tags: jasper-reports

The numbers in my report are visualized like this : **123,456.00**

I'm trying to get the number visualized like this instead: **123.456,00**

I know that I should use the patterns in iReport but I am not able to find the right pattern.

Comment: [formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10913495/876298) can help you

Comment: And this one: [Formatting currency in Jasper Reports using pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8758680/876298)

Answer (score 3):

More then pattern problem this seems to be a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) problem.

You are using an `Locale` as US and you like to use a `Locale` as example ITALY

To set desired `Local` on report generation pass it as a parameter with the key `JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE`:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>(); 
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.ITALY); 
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperReport, params); //Example of fill method use your own...
```

To set it inside of the IDE, in [ireport](/questions/tagged/ireport)

> Window>>Options>>Compilation and execution: Report Local

[image: Options]

In [jaspersoft-studio](/questions/tagged/jaspersoft-studio)

> Window>>Preferences>>Report Execution: Locale

Comment: It works, and for my country Venezuela I had to used it like this
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("es", "VE"));
Thanks