# How do I format a number as 2.564.894.621 in JasperSoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I need to print some big values. A value looks like this

> 2564894621

now I want to format the float value to this:

> 2.564.894.621

I am using Jaspersoft Studio to develop my jasper report.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best way to format in jasper report is to use the **pattern** attribute on the **textField** tag. This will keep correct class (Number), when exporting to for example excel, excel can identify it as number and will also apply same pattern.

> Properties >> TextField >> Pattern

Either you know the correct [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or you use the IDE to help you generate it

[image: IDE]

**jrxml result**

```xml
<textField pattern="#,##0">
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="25" uuid="ee49d149-394b-4ac6-a0a2-6d207b0c8d89"/>
   <textElement>
      <font fontName="DejaVu Serif" size="14"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

And exporting with a **Locale** that uses **.** as grouping separator it will display

[image: Result]

if your result is with the grouping separator **,** this does not depend on the pattern but simply your locale see this: [How to invert the comma and dot when number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440395/number-formatting-jasperreport/)

In **JasperSoft Studio** the locale used during preview can be set in

> Window>>Preferences>>Report Execution: Locale

*Note: expression like*

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0").format($F{myNumber})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

*can be used as well but its better to avoid since the export manager will treat this as text only*

Comment: I tried out the first method, the pattern works fine for me. Thanks for your helpful answer :-)

Comment: It works fine but Can I achieve this with code only with java, without changing it in jasper report. I tried with setLocale and setNumberPattern but it doesn't work quite well.
For ex `85.5` will show like `8550.0` if i set german local (in csv value is 85.5). Help is appreciated,

Comment: @Parth have you tried to set the report local fron java?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yes I tried it in java as such `dataSource.setLocale(Locale.UK);` and i use `params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.GERMAN);` and my jasper print is like this  `JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledTemplateInStreams, params, dataSource);`

Comment: @ParthPatel 5 years later, better late then ever :)