# How adding automatic Dollar symbol in JasperStudio

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I add Dollar symbol in Textfield automatic in JasperStudio Soft?
I have one Report show price, and I Want jasper studio to add an automatic $ symbol.

Comment: What do you mean by `automatic`?

Comment: Duplicate of [formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10913495/876298) & [Formatting currency in Jasper Reports using pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8758680/876298) & [Format money value according to locale and currency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13346939/876298)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use textfield patterns for displaying currencies:

There are already some predefined patterns in Jaspersoft Studio, which you could use:

[image: Patterns in Jaspersoft]

And this is how it would look like in the source code:

```
<textField pattern="¤#,##0.##;¤-#,##0.##">
```

An alternative (but also very ugly) way would be to just add the Dollar symbol in the expression:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["I am a value"+"$"]]></textFieldExpression>
```